# Unable to communicate to .Net API from Angular project

Tags: asp.net, .net, angular

I am trying to create a login page using .Net Core Web API and Angular. On button click, the login method should be called and the API call should be done, but there is some kind of error. Here is the code for the API:

```
 [HttpGet]
[Route("LoginBankUser")]
public IActionResult LoginBankUser(string username, string password)
{
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(_configuration.GetConnectionString("con1"));

    users = mongoClient.GetDatabase("bankstatement")
        .GetCollection<UserLogin>("userlogin");

    List<UserLogin> userList = users.Find(user => true).ToList();

    foreach(var u in userList)
    {
        if(u.username.Equals(username) && u.password.Equals(password))
        {
            return Ok(u.username);
        }
    }

    string resStr = "nota";
    return Ok(resStr);
}
```

This is working fine. I have checked in swagger.

Now the angular part.

The login service code:

```
private loginUrl = 'https://localhost:44340/api/Login/';

loginMethod(username:string, password:string): any {

    console.log(username)
    console.log(password)

    return this.http.get(this.loginUrl + "LoginBankUser?username=" + username
    + "&password=" + password,
    
    { headers:new HttpHeaders({
      'content-type': 'text/plain; charset=utf-8' ,
       'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*', 
       'Access-Control-Allow-Method':'*' })})

          
      }
```

Here is the .ts file code:

```
login_method(username:string, password:string):void
  {
   
    this.obj.loginMethod(username, password).subscribe(data=>
      {

        console.log(data)

        if(data.toString() != "nota"){
          //save to local storage
          localStorage.setItem('bankUserName', data.toString());

          this.router.navigate(['/home']);

        }
        else{
          alert('Invalid credentials');
        }

      })

  }
```

When I try to login it gives me this error:

```
error: {error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHtt…,
{
    "headers": {
        "normalizedNames": {},
        "lazyUpdate": null
    },
    "status": 200,
    "statusText": "OK",
    "url": "https://localhost:44340/api/Login/LoginBankUser?username=admin&password=admin",
    "ok": false,
    "name": "HttpErrorResponse",
    "message": "Http failure during parsing for https://localhost:44340/api/Login/LoginBankUser?username=admin&password=admin",
    "error": {
        "error": {},
        "text": "nota"
    }
}
```

I cannot understand what's going on.

Comment: In your API method you are returning string type instead of that return a json object or change your calling code to accept string response.

Comment: how to change calling code? can you help?

Comment: Try adding this in your client-side code-  http.get(url, {responseType: 'text'})

Comment: yep working now!

Comment: Should I add this as answer and would you mark it as accepted so that this will be useful t others as well?

Comment: yes sure add this answer

Comment: Passing data like passwords via a query string is **wildly insecure**. I hope this isn't for a real banking application. https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29598/should-sensitive-data-ever-be-passed-in-the-query-string

Comment: @Daniel no, just for a demo app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your API is returning a string value. However by default angular `httpClient` responseType is `JSON`. Hence when it tries to parse the `string` into `JSON` object it fails to do that and throws the exception.

While making the Http call you can tell that API response will be in `text` format instead of `JSON` like below:-

```
http.get(url, {responseType: 'text'})
```

It should work then after,